# How to Identify the Default App that Accepts Incoming Phone Calls in Android?

Tags: android

I'm simply trying to find out which app is the default app to handle phone calls on my Android test device. Right now, I'm using the following code, this SHOULD work, but always returns null:

```
Intent phoneApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);

ResolveInfo app = mPM.resolveActivity(phoneApp, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Any ideas? It seems there is no documentation on this for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryIntentActivities() on PackageManager to find out all the applications that could handle that intent, but that's the most you can do.

Unfortunately, there is no way to find out the default application that gets called for that implicit intent (aside from calling that implicit intent yourself, and seeing which application gets launched afterwards)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you so much, I think I will resort to calling the intent and seeing what is launched. Any ideas of how I could approach this reliably?

Comment: Dang, unfortunately you can't even use queryIntentActivities() to determine this... I believe you have to deal solely with TelephonyManager to do anything with the phone..

Comment: You're probably right about the telephony manager, however calling that implicit intent yourself, and seeing which application gets launched afterwards, should still be possible (even if it's a hackish way of doing it). It's just that I don't have the time to research that topic for you right now.

Comment: Hi Stephan, no, I understand, however, I researched doing just that and it doesn't seem possible either.