# Why is it Not Possible to Determine the Default Phone Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a unique situation where I have to query the phone to determine which app will be handling incoming phone calls. I realize that in 95% of cases com.android.phone is doing this work, however, I can't only be right 95% of the time, I need to know 100% of the time what app it'll be (user could have installed a custom phone app afterall to handle calls).

Being familiar with intents, I figured I could simply ask PackageManager to identify all apps that could handle these actions: Intent.ACTION_ANSWER and or Intent.ACTION_CALL (the only two Intent actions relevant to phone calls), after all, this approach works for virtually all other phone functions I've tried.

Unfortunately, whenever one tries to query PackageManager, say either using .resolveActivity() or .queryIntentActivities(), the result is always 'null', even when default applications exist for these intents. To further compound my frustration, there's absolutely zero documentation on why these intent actions can't be utilized. The documentation reads as if I am doing everything exactly right to reach my objective.

**So, the question is two-fold: is there any reasonable method whatsoever to determine the phone app (hopefully the default app) AND why the heck can't intent actions created for this exact purpose be utilized?**

**TL;DR** There's two intent actions that relate to phone calls, except, you can't use these to query PackageManager to find the underlying apps that facilitate these intent actions. Why not?

Comment: You've asked this question before. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664257/packagemanager-resolveactivity-always-returns-null-for-intent-action-answer-th and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666442/how-to-identify-the-default-app-that-accepts-incoming-phone-calls-in-android

Comment: In my opinon they are all different based on nuiances. I am asking WHY these intents don't work in this question. In the other questions, I was still determining HOW to do this at all.
Besides, this is a pretty MAJOR disappointment for me as the documentation says squat, there's nothing online about this whatsoever, and I'm flabberghasted that there's no reasoning available. It's insanity.

Comment: I deleted one of the two above as it was the most unuseful. This one, and the other one, I believe are useful for people doing searches on this problem.

Comment: Well, there's always documentation because the source code is available. If you have any doubt about how Intent resolution works, see the code.

Comment: Hi dtmilano, I guess, but why in the documentation does it mislead? That doesn't make sense to me.